# Can I get the HttpContext from a Health check in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, health-check

I have implemented [Health checks in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-8.0) with a custom health check. In my class which implements `IHealthCheck`, I inject `IHttpContextAccessor`. This resolves correctly, but when I try to access the `HttpContext` property of it, it is always null. I have multiple endpoints defined for my health checks and I am trying to determine within the check which endpoint was called. Is there a way to make HttpContext accessible or is there some other way to get the context of which endpoint was called passed into the health check?

**Edit** - I added a `Debug.WriteLine()` statement to print out the path in the `HttpContext`. What's odd is that it does print it out if I hit the original '/healthz' endpoint, but then it also prints out a blank value as well. If I hit one of the new endpoints of '/healthz/live-probe' or '/healthz/readiness-probe', it seems to be blank every time. Also, the timing of the printed out values does not match up with when the request was made. If I had to guess, it would seem that the health checks are done in a loop in a background process and then the endpoints just return the results from the latest health check run. If that's true, that would explain why the `HttpContext` is null, but it doesn't explain why it's not null for the '/healthz' endpoint some of the time. Besides the article I linked to above, is there some documentation that might explain this behavior?

Here is the extension method that created the endpoints:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseHealthCheckEndpoint(this IApplicationBuilder app) =>
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/healthz",
            new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                Predicate = _ => true,
                ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse,
                ResultStatusCodes = Statuses
            });
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/healthz/live-probe",
            new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                Predicate = check => check.Tags.Contains(LivenessTag),
                ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse,
                ResultStatusCodes = Statuses
            });
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/healthz/ready-probe",
            new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                Predicate = check => check.Tags.Contains(ReadinessTag),
                ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse,
                ResultStatusCodes = Statuses
            });
    });
```

Here is the extension method the microservice would call to add a health check:

```
public static IHealthChecksBuilder AddHealthCheckUrls(this IHealthChecksBuilder healthChecksBuilder,
    string name,
    HealthStatus? failureStatus = null,
    IEnumerable<string> tags = null,
    TimeSpan? timeout = null,
    HttpMethod httpMethod = null,
    params string[] urls)
{
    return healthChecksBuilder.Add(new HealthCheckRegistration(
        name: name,
        factory: s => new UrlHealthCheck(s.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>(), s.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>(), httpMethod, failureStatus.HasValue, urls),
        failureStatus: failureStatus,
        tags: new List<string> { "urls" }.Concat(tags ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>()),
        timeout: timeout));
}
```

Here is the health check itself:

```
internal class UrlHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly string[] _urls;
    private readonly HttpMethod _httpMethod = HttpMethod.Head;
    private readonly bool _hasUserFailureStatus;

    public UrlHealthCheck(bool hasUserFailureStatus) => _hasUserFailureStatus = hasUserFailureStatus;

    public UrlHealthCheck(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, HttpMethod httpMethod, bool hasUserFailureStatus, params string[] urls)
    {
        if ((urls?.Length ?? 0) == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Urls cannot be empty", nameof(urls));
        _urls = urls;
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClientFactory), "IHttpClientFactory could not be resolved. Ensure you are calling 'services.AddHttpClient();' from your ConfigureServices method.");
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor), "IHttpContextAccessor could not be resolved. Ensure you are calling 'services.AddHttpContextAccessor();' from your ConfigureServices method.");
        _httpMethod = httpMethod ?? HttpMethod.Head;
        _hasUserFailureStatus = hasUserFailureStatus;
    }

    public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new())
    {
        var isLivenessProbe = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request?.Path.Value?.Contains("live-probe") ?? false;
        var isReadinessProbe = !isLivenessProbe && (_httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request?.Path.Value?.Contains("ready-probe") ?? false);
        var defaultFailureStatus = isReadinessProbe ? HealthStatus.Degraded : HealthStatus.Unhealthy;
        var failureStatus = _hasUserFailureStatus ? context.Registration.FailureStatus : defaultFailureStatus;

        try
        {
            // Prevent infinite dependency loops.
            var depthCount = 0;
            StringValues dependencyDepthCount = default;
            _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request?.Query.TryGetValue(nameof(dependencyDepthCount), out dependencyDepthCount);
            if (dependencyDepthCount.Count > 0 && int.TryParse(dependencyDepthCount[0], out depthCount))
            {
                if (depthCount > 5)
                {
                    return new HealthCheckResult(HealthStatus.Healthy, "Dependency depth count exceeded");
                }
            }

            using var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

            var tasks = _urls.Select(url =>
            {
                var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
                var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
                query["dependencyDepthCount"] = (depthCount + 1).ToString();
                uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();

                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(_httpMethod, uriBuilder.Uri);
                return client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            });

            var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            return result.All(x => x.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                ? new HealthCheckResult(HealthStatus.Healthy)
                : new HealthCheckResult(failureStatus, "One or more requests failed", data: new Dictionary<string, object>(result.Where(r => !r.IsSuccessStatusCode).Select(r => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(r.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsolutePath, r.ReasonPhrase))));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new HealthCheckResult(failureStatus, exception: ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here is how the microservice would add the healthcheck:

```
        services.AddOurCompanyHealthChecks<UserServiceContext>(tags: new string[] { "User Microservice" })
            .AddHealthCheckUrls("Some dependency", tags: new string[] { HealthCheckBuilderExtensions.ReadinessTag }, urls: $"{Configuration["Services:UserService:BaseUrl"]}/healthz");
```

Comment: Was not able to reproduce. Do you have a [mre]? Can you please post it somewhere (like github)?

Comment: HttpContext was not null on myside,please share more details related

Comment: @RuikaiFeng, please see edits above.

Comment: Please post your configuration code. Have you configured a [health check publisher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-8.0#health-check-publisher), or are you using a Xabaril publisher? In that case the health checks are executed on a schedule and pushed to listeners. In general, collecting health checks and *publishing* them are two different operations.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, code was added. No publisher, I'm just hitting the endpoints locally in my browser.